# mysql INSERT INTO query - ERROR with syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help with advising what may be wrong with my insert into syntax please ?
        Working except i am receiving empty query message

```
    // values sent from form
    $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $yob=$_POST['yob'];

    /*********** CONNECT TO THE DATABASE ******/
    //Step 1 CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
   $db=mysql_connect ("localhost", “db_username, “db_password);
   if (!$db) {
     die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
     }
     //Step2 SELECT THE DATABASE
     $db_select = mysql_select_db(“db_name,$db);
    if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "Welcome $first_name!";
    echo " Success, connected to database but maybe not the table";

    // Insert data into database
    //##############################I THINK PROBLEM MUST BE HERE IN THIS    INSERT       STATEMENT STATEMENT###################################
    $sql="INSERT INTO newsletter-subscribers(first_name, last_name, email,    postcode, gender,    yob)VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$postcode','$gender','$yob')";
    if(mysql_query($sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
    } else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysql_error($db);
    }
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: a little more white space around values ? ah yes the table name becomes a subtraction

Comment: The message that appears on the screen after submitting my form is Welcome Fifty-seven! Success, connected to database but maybe not the tableERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO newsletter-subscribers(first_name, last_name, email, postcode, gender, yob)VALUES('Fifty-seven','Testing','email-address','2000','Male','1995'). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-subscribers(first_name, last_name, email, postcode, gender, yob)VALUES('Fifty-s' at line 1

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. If any of your values contain quotes this would fail.

Comment: doing math here? `newsletter-subscribers` <<<

Comment: newsletter minus subscribers equals pumpernickel

Comment: @Dagon what about the rye?

Comment: @Fred-ii- what ever is used, we know, you're the spoon smart enough to eat it.

Comment: @Dagon "eat"? is that what you do with it?

Comment: feed it to Reg if he ever comes back he will need the energy to fix all the mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query,

```
$sql="INSERT INTO newsletter-subscribers(first_name, last_name, email,    postcode, gender,    yob)VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$postcode','$gender','$yob')";
```

Your new query,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `newsletter-subscribers` (first_name, last_name, email, postcode, gender, yob) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$postcode','$gender','$yob')";
```

So, what has changed?

- Added ticks around your table name.
- Removed spaces which you didn't need to make query clearer.

Without the backticks around your table name, `MySQL` is treating it as **newsletter** *minus* **subscribers**. Which is wrong, add the ticks to tell `MySQL` that it is a table name.

**Edit 1**

**This might be a copy & paste error, I'm not sure, however...**

Your db connect is incorrect too, you aren't assigning any values to it as your quotes are not closed and are *smart quotes*.

Your connect,

```
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost", “db_username, “db_password);
```

Your new connect,

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_username"," db_password");
```

Also,

```
$db_select = mysql_select_db(“db_name,$db);
```

To,

```
$db_select = mysql_select_db("db_name", $db);
```

Notice the difference in the quotes.

**Edit 2**

Your code is prone to [`SQL injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you are still using `MySQL` even though it has been deprecated, you should use either `MySQLi` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Not to mention your `$_POST` data is being passed on to the query without being sanitized, you should start using `htmlspecialchars` it would make it better and prevent `XSS`.

Comment: even better dont use hyphens! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: not closed and are smart quotes, not the proper ones

Comment: smart meaning dumb :-0

Comment: `("localhost", “db_username, “db_password)` to `("localhost", "db_username","db_password")` and `(“db_name,$db)` to `("db_name",$db)` dang those curly quotes ;-) if that's what they're really using. Just in case.

Comment: Thank you all for your help with this especially Script47 for taking the time to explain it the way you have. I have never placed a hyphen between a table name before so have learned a lesson ove 8 hours trying to figure out what i was doing wrong. My original code had the correct quotes - not sure how the curly quotes ended up being pasted here. Dan Lowe, you hit it the nail on the head also, that was a main issue. Now I can work on the sanitising part - Once again Thank you and have a great day :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your table name contains a dash, so you need to quote it. The backtick or back-quote character is used to quote symbol names in MySQL (such as the names of tables, columns, etc), so you would need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `newsletter-subscribers` (first_name, ...
```

Comment: **backtick**  not quote

Comment: Yes, backticks are the way you quote a table name in mysql. The example shows that.

Comment: ok its just confusing grammar, i'll settle for the manuals version: The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):